# Tensorflow: How can I save a checkpoint only if the error is minimized during training?

Tags: tensorflow

I am running a tensorflow program and I want to store the best model for later use. I am using *estimator* (`tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator` module that takes a run_config argument, where I set `save_checkpoints_secs=20*60`) for training.

estimator.train takes a train_input_fn and num_train_steps as arguments. 
eg:  `estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=num_train_steps)`

Instead of saving the checkpoint after every 'n' seconds, I want to store the best model which has minimal error while training.

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tf.estimator.BestExporter seems like it's exactly what you're looking for. According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/BestExporter), it states:

> This class performs a model export every time when the new model is
>   better than any existing model.

```
  estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
      config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(
          model_dir='/my_model', save_summary_steps=100),
      feature_columns=[categorial_feature_a_emb, ...],
      hidden_units=[1024, 512, 256])

  serving_feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(
      categorial_feature_a_emb)
  serving_input_receiver_fn = (
      tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
      serving_feature_spec))

  exporter = tf.estimator.BestExporter(
      name="best_exporter",
      serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn,
      exports_to_keep=5)

  train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(...)

  eval_spec = [tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
    input_fn=eval_input_fn,
    steps=100,
    exporters=exporter,
    start_delay_secs=0,
    throttle_secs=5)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I went through the documentation and it seems a good solution